# how to disable mouse over function when data type is not image

Tags: jquery

I have a database,I'm keeping datas in there. In my database there is paths of file's which has .pdf,.docx,.jpg,.png and such. In my web project, I want to build a image preview section in datatable. I build datatable dynamically. So I want to disable mouse over function, when the query result is not image. I wrote this codes for this.

```
    <script>
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' )){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
function getData(){

    $('#example tbody').html('');
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO_copy:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName_copy:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType_copy:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            var html='';
            var arrayExtensions=['jpg','JPG','JPG File','jpeg','JPEG image','PNG','TIFF image','tiff'];
            $.each(docs,function(key,value){
                console.log(value.extType[0]);
                    if(arrayExtensions.indexOf(value.extType)===-1){
                        $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
                    }

                    else{
                        $(document).on("mouseover", ".preview", function() {

                              $(this).find('img').fadeIn();
                            });
                        $(document).on("mouseout",".preview",function(){
                            $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
                        });
                    }
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><button id="'+value.FilePath+'" type="button" onclick="openDocument(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</td>';
                html+='<td class="ImagePreview"><a href="#" class="preview">Image Preview<img id="showImage" src="'+value.FilePath+'" class="hide-image"></a></td>';
                html+='</tr>';

            });
            $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#example tbody').html(html);
            var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting" : [],

            });
        },
    });


};
</script>
```

But when I do mouse over, there is no action. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking mouseover on whole the document. However you could use the :not selector here in jQuery.

The * selector selects ALL elements. So if we combine these two we get this:

```
$('*:not(img)').on('mouseover', function() {
  console.log('Not an image!');
});
```

However applying this on your code, you probably going to have something like this:

```
$('.preview:not(img)').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
}
```

To check the file extension, you could best place them in an array. Then your code can by reduced a lot by writing it like this

```
// If extension is not in the array it will return -1
if (arrayExtensions.indexOf(value.extType) === -1) {
  $(this).find('img').fadeOut();
}
```

However you are constructing your HTML in your js. So you could set a mouseover on the rows with the class you want. So basically:

```
if(arrayExtensions.indexOf(value.extType)===-1){
     html+='<tr>';
   }
else 
   {
     html+='<tr class=".thisHasMouseOver">';                  
   }
 $('.thisHasMouseOver').on('mouseover', function(){
    // Do stuff
   }
```

Comment: One more important condition, I have to check data type which comes from database. If data type is not image type,so I must disable mouseover.

Comment: The code above puts the mouseover on all elements but images.. Are there any image types that do need a mouseover?

Comment: I understand. I have a one more question. Can I check data type is image or not using if statement in jquery?

Comment: Can't you use value.doctype for this?

Comment: No, it defines document's category. The `value.extType` includes document's type.

Comment: I tried it and it closes all table row's mouseover. We're very close to do it. For example, the first row's data type is `.pdf`and the second row's data type is `.jpg`. I want to show image when I do mouseover second row; when I do mouseover first row, I want to disable it.

Comment: Could you update your question with the rendered html? That way I can understand it better :)